# How can I use rollup in order to bundle files containing es7 code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, rollupjs, ecmascript-2016

While currently supported by Chrome, rollup rejects my es7 code:

```
[!] Error: Unexpected token
static/app.js (8:14)
 6:
 7: class App extends Component {
 8:   static name = 'MyES7App';

Error: Unexpected token
    at error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:9435:30)
    at Module.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:13407:9)
    at tryParse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:13320:16)
    at Module.setSource (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:13630:33)
    at Promise.resolve.catch.then.then.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:16460:20)
```

Is there a way to make it work? All I want is to bundle/minimize up some files into one, without taking care of cross-browser support or even transpiling.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, to be able to minify source code, tool should *know about it*. It is nearly impossible to minify source code like "plain text", all you can do is remove newlines and extra spaces. Minimizers are using parsers, to generate abstract syntax tree from the source code, and then works with this AST.

Rollup uses [Acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) as JS parser, and by default it doesn't support class members. Even though they are available in Chrome, they are not in EcmaScript standard yet, it is [proposal on stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

So you need either different parser (like Babylon, which goes with Babel), or somehow teach Acorn of new language features.

I guess easiest way is to setup Babel and use [rollup-plugin-babel](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel), to support new syntax and proposals.

UPD Here is related [Rollup issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1185), but looks like suggested Acorn solution is not working anymore...